# Selenium Webdriver - How to termintate session if the browser died?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, exception, webdriver

Need some help in Selenium Webdriver (PHP Webdriver, however, java / JS / Python examples will also help)

A scenario - during an execution of a test case, the browser (Firefox, chrome) died unexpectedly. How can I catch the exception and stop the session execution?

the exception / error trace:

```
"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException' with message 'Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died."
```

Any help will be appritiated

A code for example:

```html
<?php 

/**
 * Exceptions in PHPWebdriver
 * 
 * @date: 30/01/2017
 * @Author: AlexG
 */

namespace Facebook\WebDriver;
//====================H-E-A-D-E-R====================//

require_once('/home/brdev/qa/br_qa_projects/webdriver_checker/browserstack/tools/vendor/autoload.php');
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException;

// Test case with Firefox
if($argv[1]=="0")    
 $web_driver = RemoteWebDriver::create("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",array("platform"=>"WINDOWS", "browserName"=>"firefox"),(150*1000),(150*1000));

// Test case with Chrome
else if($argv[1]=="1")
 $web_driver = RemoteWebDriver::create("http://127.0.0.1:9515",array("platform"=>"WINDOWS", "browserName"=>"chrome"),(150*1000),(150*1000));

// launch test case
$web_driver->get('http://SomeWebsiteHere.com');

// Input registration details to the necessary fields
sleep(5);

$web_driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("first_name"))->sendKeys("Browserstack");
$web_driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("last_name"))->sendKeys("TestInPHP");
$web_driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("phone_num"))->sendKeys("123456789");
$web_driver->executeScript("document.getElementById('country').selectedIndex = '1';", array());
$web_driver->executeScript("document.getElementById('user_email').value = '$email';", array());
sleep(5);

##### Let's say the browser dies here. for some reason

// Submit the form
$web_driver->executeScript("document.getElementById('submit').click();", array());

// Save the time when click was done
$initTime = time();
$flag = true;

$web_driver->quit();

?>
```

Comment: what do you want to stop the execution. won't it be stopped automatically due to exception.

Comment: The point is that I need to catch the exception (Then log it in the results log for other purposes) and I don't know how. 

Another point is that while testing using services like Browserstack, a session is not dead in case of an exception and enters a "Zombie" state, thus blocking the other test cases from being executed, until timeout.

Comment: do you know which line causes this failure. You can put a try/catch around that.